# Use JSON file in postgresql database

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table in a postgresql database with one field with json format.
It's look like this :

```
[
  {
    "transition": "transition1",
    "from": "step1",
    "to": "step2",
    "date": {
      "date": "2021-01-30 15:34:06.840859"
    }
  },
  {
    "transition": "transition2",
    "from": "step2",
    "to": "step3",
    "date": {
      "date": "2021-01-30 16:52:00.412208"
    }
  }
]
```

I want to have a new column with the date of transition1.
I tried a lot of things but I can't figure out how to extract this date, I can't use the index because the number of transition is not fixed, some user could have 3 and other more than 10.

Comment: What is your Postgres version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over all array elements to find the correct one:

```
select (select (item -> 'date' ->> 'date')::timestamp
        from jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_column) as x(item)
        where item ->> 'transition' = 'transition1') as transition_date
from the_table
;
```

If you column is defined as `json` rather than `jsonb` (which it should be) you need to use `json_array_elements()` instead.

Comment: My version is : 11.6

Can I use the same thing not to update the table but select this value ?

Comment: @J.doe: yes you can put that expression into a SELECT